# JMeter - How to rampup a specific number of users and to control their iteration per second

Tags: jmeter

I've a requirement for a performance test which says:
To ramp-up in 30 minutes, hold the iterations for 60 minutes and then to ramp-down in 30 minutes.

The Iteration includes 6 transactions
The Iteration time takes 10 seconds average to go through the 6 transactions

I always face an issue to make a ramp-up which corresponds with firing 2 iterations per seconds.

Would you pls help with this in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see how you can fit 2 iterations which take 20 seconds into 1 second so you need to come up with better explanation like what is throughput (requests per second to start with, how many requests per second you want to add each second or minute of the ramp-up, etc.)

With regards to implementation itself I believe you're looking for [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination.

In Throughput Shaping Timer you can easily define ramp-up/ramp-down behaviour as well as the time to hold the load:

[image]

and you can connect it to the Concurrency Thread Group via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function):

[image]

this way Concurrency Thread Group will be able to kick off extra threads (virtual users) if current amount is not enough to reach/maintain the defined throughput.

This way you can precisely control the number of requests per second at each stage of your performance test.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T
We expect to have a load of 2 users to login on the web application per second and to perform the following actions (Login, click on tab XXXX, Select option XXXX, download an PDF file and then Logout).

This is why I need to simulate 2 logins per second and to maintain it for 60 minutes. 
ramp-up: 30 min,  maintain 2 logins per second for 60 min and  ramp-down in 30 min
The main purpose is to maintain 2 logins per second for one hour.

Comment: Also, we can modify the configuration of the ramp-up and ramp-down intervals as we need within the 30 minutes for each